# r - ggplot with two data.frames, legend wrong identifiers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot and I was able to get the plot that I want. 
But when I tried to add a legend, something went wrong. The legend has different shapes, sizes and linetypes; the only correct match is the color.

Here is the code, with simulated data:

```
library(ggplot)
set.seed(5703)
# DATA 1
x1 <- seq(1, 100)
y1 <- rnorm(mean = 50, sd = 10, length(x1))
df1 <- data.frame(x1, y1)
head(df1)

# DATA 2
x2 <- seq(1, 100, 5)
y2 <- rnorm(mean = 50, sd = 2, length(x2))
df2 <- data.frame(x2, y2)
head(df2)

# Plot: DATA 1 and DATA 2
p101 <- ggplot (df1, aes( x = x1, y = y1) ) +
  geom_point(aes(color="Vals every 1sec - shape circle"), shape = 1, size = 4 ) +
  geom_line (aes(color="Vals every 1sec - shape circle"), size = 0.5, linetype= "dotdash") +
  geom_point(data= df2, aes(x = x2, y = y2, color="Vals every 5sec - shape: triangle & bigger, line: thicker"), shape= 2, size= 6 ) + 
  geom_line (data= df2, aes(x = x2, y = y2, color="Vals every 5sec - shape: triangle & bigger, line: thicker"), size = 1.25, linetype = "solid" ) +
  scale_colour_manual("", values=c("Vals every 1sec - shape circle" = "#e66101", 
                                   "Vals every 5sec - shape: triangle & bigger, line: thicker" = "#5e3c99" ) )+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.7,0.1) )+
  labs (title = "Graph Nr. 101", x = "Time [s]", y = "Values")
p101
# legend is mixed up, it is not showing the correct shapes and sizes for each data
```

Here is the image:

[image: ggplot df1 and df2 wrong legend]

You will notice that both items on the legend have a circle and a triangle, same size and linetype.

Maybe the plot code is entirely wrong, so I am open to any suggestions and ready to learn :)

Comment: It would be simpler to `rbind` your data together with an identifier variable for which data.frame it came from, e.g. `library(dplyr); bind_rows(setNames(df1, c('x', 'y')), setNames(df2, c('x', 'y')), .id = 'line') %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, linetype = line, color = line, shape = line)) + geom_point() + geom_line() `, though you'll need to clean up scales to match your preferences.

Comment: Ohh thanks for your fast reply @alistaire it seems pretty  similar to what has coded. Thumb up !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add in the legend and theme changes but this should get you to where you want.

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(5703)
# DATA 1
x1 <- seq(1, 100)
y1 <- rnorm(mean = 50, sd = 10, length(x1))
df1 <- data.frame(x = x1, y = y1, group = "A")
head(df1)

# DATA 2
x2 <- seq(1, 100, 5)
y2 <- rnorm(mean = 50, sd = 2, length(x2))
df2 <- data.frame(x = x2, y = y2, group = "B")
head(df2)

df <- bind_rows(df1, df2)

# Plot: DATA 1 and DATA 2
p101 <- ggplot (df, aes( x = x, y = y, color = group) ) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = group), size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = group), size = 4 )
```

Comment: I have seen a lot of ggplots using melt or bind_rows, in order to get the expected results. What was wrong on my code? Could please tell me what I was not thinking clear? Any reading suggestions? Thanks